# How much currency in cash for trip to Turkey?

Tags: money, turkey, exchange

How much Turkish lira should I take for two of us?

We will have four nights in Istanbul.

We are planning to visit 2-3 museums and will use public transport. We will a book hotel with breakfast and are planning to dine out once per day along with some light snacks. I am also planning to do a short Bosporus cruise tour and we might do some shopping. Just a rough estimate, will 2000 Turkish lira will be enough?

**Note**: I don't want to use my master card there as I am not sure that my card will work internationally and even if it worked I will loose a lot on service charges.

Comment: Experiences vary but for me getting cash in a foreign currency from my own bank or a currency exchange is usually more expensive than getting the local currency at my  destination using an ATM with the debit card associated to my checking account. Inquire at your bank if your debit card can be used abroad, if and what they will charge per transaction,  how the exchange rate they will charge you will differ from the interbank rates. My credit cards work in a pinch but their fees are higher than on my debit  card